# jQuery toggle table element: use "display: block" rather than "display: table"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to toggle the visibility of a table element.

When I hide the element and then show it again, I find that jQuery has added `display: table` to the element.

However, I really want this to be `display: block` instead, for styling reasons.

Is there a way I can force it to be `display: block`?

JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LNKyr/

Comment: `.toggle` has been deprecated from JQuery AFAIK

Comment: @Paulie_D [This `toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is not deprecated, the other toggle is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 3):

Just set it to `block` to begin with and that is what jquery will set it back to:

```
table{
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LNKyr/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#itemid").css("display","block");
```

execute this after you show the item.